# Построчная проверка списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, find

Есть два списка (один с ключевыми словами, второй с объемным текстом, где в каждой из строк 100% встретиться одно из ключевых слов первого списка).

Как можно построчно проверять списки и искать значения из одной строки списка во вех строках другого списка?

Сложность для меня в том, что не совсем понимаю, как проверять именно каждую строчку на поиск слова в каждой строчке, так же списки могут быть объемные, свыше 5000 строк.

```
authors = ["Толстой", "Чехов", "Пушкин"]
texts = ["псевдоним Чехова был А-т Чехонте", "Пушкин погиб в дуэли"]

found_count = sum(any(a in text for a in authors) for text in texts)
```

также:

```
for line in y: 
    for aut in x: 
        if aut in line: povtor=povtor+1
```

где:

- `y` - список строк в котором ищутся слова, а
- `x` - список ключевых слов:

Comment: покажите пожалуйста, что вы пробовали делать.

Comment: '''authors = ["Толстой", "Чехов", "Пушкин"]'''
'''texts = ["псевдоним Чехова был А-т Чехонте", "Пушкин погиб в дуэли"]'''
'''found_count = sum(any(a in text for a in authors) for text in texts)'''
также:
'''for line in y:
    for aut  in x:
        if aut in line:
            povtor=povtor+1'''
где "y" - список строк в котором ищутся слова, а "x" - список ключевых слов:

Comment: прикреплять код в комментариях плохая идея.. сами хоть поняли, что тут написано?

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так:

```
authors = ["Толстой", "Чехов", "Пушкин"]

texts = [
    "псевдоним Чехова был А-т Чехонте",  
    "АЛЕКСАНДР СЕРГЕЕВИЧ ПУШКИН - ВЕЛИКИЙ РУССКИЙ ПОЭТ И ПИСАТЕЛЬ.",
    "Граф Лев Николаевич Толстой — один из наиболее известных русских "
    "писателей и мыслителей, один из величайших писателей-романистов мира. "
]

for author in authors:
    for text in texts:
        if text.lower().find(author.lower()) != -1:
            print(f'{author}: {text}\n')
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

ИМХО, с точки зрения последующего использования, целесообразней создать словарь. В дальнейшем можно обращаться к списку упоминаний по фамилии писателя

```py
from pprint import pprint

authors = ["Толстой", "Чехов", "Пушкин"]

texts = ["псевдоним Чехова был А-т Чехонте",  
    "АЛЕКСАНДР СЕРГЕЕВИЧ ПУШКИН - ВЕЛИКИЙ РУССКИЙ ПОЭТ И ПИСАТЕЛЬ.",
    "Граф Лев Николаевич Толстой — один из наиболее известных русских писателей и мыслителей, один из величайших писателей-романистов мира. "
]

references = dict()
for author in authors:
   references[author] = references.setdefault(author, []) + [*filter(lambda x: author.lower() in x.lower(), texts)]

pprint(references, indent=2)

# { 'Пушкин': ['АЛЕКСАНДР СЕРГЕЕВИЧ ПУШКИН - ВЕЛИКИЙ РУССКИЙ ПОЭТ И ПИСАТЕЛЬ.'],
#   'Толстой': ['Граф Лев Николаевич Толстой — один из наиболее известных русских писателей и мыслителей, один из величайших писателей-романистов мира. '],
#   'Чехов': ['псевдоним Чехова был А-т Чехонте']}
```

> справедливости ради нужно заметить, что данный подход к решению этой задчи, из разряда "побырому на коленке", поскольку если в списке попадется, к примеру, Цветаева, то предложение где будет использована форма слова "Цветаевой" это решение пропустит. Поэтому если необходим более точный поиск обратите внимание на библиотеку `pymorphy2`

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте обратил внимание на регулярные выражения. Очень интересная и на мой взгляд нужная тема, хотя многие ее не любят и стараются писать собственные алгоритмы поиска при простейших задачах.

Итак, модуль для `python` - это `re`

Пишите некий шаблон

```
import re
pattern = r'Пушкин' # можно создать список шаблонов и забирать оттуда
```

И у модуля `re` имеются функции по поиску, например `search`:

```
>>> re.search(pattern, 'Пушкин был ...') 
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='Пушкин'>
```

Ответ является объектом, который содержит интервал строки где было найдено и какое совпадение.

Тема регулярных выражений достаточно обширна, поэтому здесь простейший пример. Управлять поиском можно не только задавать конкретные значения строки, но и шаблоны, которые могут принимать определенные значения. Например: 10 цифр подряд, или шаблон для номера телефона или mac адреса и т.д.

Здесь можно почитать:

[Оф документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

[Хабр-статейка](https://habr.com/ru/post/349860/)

Что касаемо логики вашей задачи, то многое зависит от того как вы читаете строки и какие выходные данные вам нужны. Если вы читаете из файла то существует опция `readline()`. Напишите функцию, которая при чтении одной линии из файла будет вам давать `True` при совпадении и позицию знаков в строке.